# Can iText support GS1 DataMatrix

Tags: java, gs1-datamatrix

I just started working on iText to generate PDF document. I need to generate GS1 standard DataMatrix barcodes. Can anybody share sample code snippet?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: We don't give out example code on SO. Research some on the internet or another resource

Comment: I verified in internet for GS1 Data Matrix barcode support with iText library. I did not  find any proper information. My question is Does iText support GS1 Data Matrix barcodes?

Comment: Any update on this or ended up using workaround? I have tried to use ```BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_EXTENSION``` but not sure if it is a correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the iText documentation [`com.itextpdf.barcodes.BarcodeDataMatrix`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.7/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeDataMatrix.html) but seems that none of options are capable of generating a standard GS1 DataMatrix.

So I have instead used another library [OkapiBarcode](https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode) to generate a GS1 DataMatrix image and import that image into my document:

```java
DataMatrix dataMatrix = new DataMatrix();
dataMatrix.setDataType(Symbol.DataType.GS1);
// Remember to use '[' and ']'
String targetDataMatrixCode = "[01]03453120000011[17]191125[10]ABCD1234";
// Preferred Size indicates the Data Matrix Size
dataMatrix.setPreferredSize(5);
dataMatrix.setContent(targetDataMatrixCode);
// Generate BufferedImage
BufferedImage dataMatrixImage = new BufferedImage(dataMatrix.getWidth(), dataMatrix.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics2D g2d = dataMatrixImage.createGraphics();
Java2DRenderer renderer = new Java2DRenderer(g2d, 1, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
renderer.render(dataMatrix);
// Then you can continue processing display with dataMatrixImage
...
```

So points to notice for the above code:

- You have to use `[` and `]` first for GS1 parentheses as the library will help you convert them into `(` and `)` and do further processing
- The conversion of preferred size to Data Matrix size is included as Javadoc comments. You can check for the function [`setPreferredSize(int)`](https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/org/okapibarcode/backend/DataMatrix.java). You should explicitly call this function if you want to fix your Data Matrix to a certain size